# how to use this ,https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options ,predefined ranges ,in my svelte project, is it possible to use, any solutions

Tags: svelte, daterangepicker

i am not able to convert this daterangepicker, which has predefine ranges, is it possible to use this code to convert and use it in svelte with full functionality, Thank you

i tried using svelte syntax, and imported required libraries css etc but no luck